# Exportar todas las base de datos a traves de un script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

Estoy intentando hacer un script para exportar todas las base de datos, estoy probando en un servidor local y estoy probando con el siguiente codigo:

```
for DataB in `mysql -e "show databases" -u root`; do
mysqldump -u root $DataB > "$DataB.sql";
```

done

pero me muestra los siguientes errores:

- mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'Database' when selecting the database
- mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES
- mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT, LOCK TABLES command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'accounts' when using LOCK TABLES

tengo poco tiempo trabajando con linux, antes de hacer esta pregunta intente buscar informacion pero no pude resolver.

Adicional a esto, tengo una duda cuando se incluye codigo mysql en un script, las comillas `` son para encerrar el codigo mysql? y las comillas dobles "" serian para que?

Gracias de antemano a todo el que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Son varias preguntas y no sé como responderlas en orden.

Primero, cuando escribes `mysql -e "show databases" -u root` lo que obtienes es una lista bien presentada de tus bases de datos, es decir, obtienes algo semejante como resultado.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| base1              |
| base2              |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| etcetera           |
+--------------------+
```

Cuando encierras `mysql -e "show databases" -u root` entre las *backticks* (`` ` ``) lo que se realiza es una operación llamada *command substitution*, es decir, lo que se ejecute dentro de esos caracteres reemplazará el nombre de "algo".

Cuando tu escribes `for DataB in` itera sobre los valores de ese "algo", que en este caso sería el resultado de lo obtenido con la consulta con el cliente de `mysql`.

Sugiero que en lugar de usar las *backticks* utilices mejor la sintaxis `$(comando)`, por ejemplo

```
for DataB in $(mysql -e "show databases" -u root)
...
```

En el bucle *for*, la variable `DataB` va a almacenar, en cada iteración de cada valor, el valor de cada uno de los resultados, entonces, siguiendo la salida de ese comando que puse anteriormente, el primer resultado que te saldría sería el de `Database` y dudo mucho que tengas una base de datos llamada `Database`, entonces podrías escapar ese valor.

Si miras los errores con atención (mirar los errores es tu mejor aliado) uno dice

> Unknown database 'Database'

Lo cual nos dice que se le esta pasando la cadena `Database` como parámetro a `mysqldump` y este indica que no existe, desde ahí esta una falla en nuestra obtención de las bases.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES

Ahí vemos que a `mysqldump` no le "gusta" algo referente a la tabla `information_schema`.

Algo que podrías hacer sería copiar y pegar esto.

```
for dbase in $( mysql -e "show databases" -u root )
do
    [[ "$dbase" != "Database" && "$dbase" != *"_schema" ]] && mysqldump -u <usuario> -p<contraseña> "$dbase" > "$dbase.sql"
done
```

Eso es si quieres evitar exportar las tablas como `information_schema` o `performance_schema`

O

```
for dbase in $( mysql -e "show databases" -u root )
do
    [[ "$dbase" != "Database" ]] && mysqldump --single-transaction -u <usuario> -p<contraseña> "$dbase" > "$dbase.sql"
done
```

Si es que quieres las tablas que tengan los metadatos. De esta manera puede que te salga un error sobre la tabla `information_schema` que te puede tener sin preocupaciones.

Otra opción que podría usar es la escrita en el manual de `mysqldump` `man 1 mysqldump`

```
mysqldump -u <usuario> -p<contraseña> -h <host> --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Para exportar todas las bases de datos en el archivo `all_databases.sql`

Para aclarar, nota como después del parámetro `-p` pongo seguidamente, y sin espacios, la indicación de escribas ahí la contraseña.

## Nota sobre la seguridad.

Hay que aclarar que hacer estas operaciones, con la contraseña expuesta en la terminal, es peligroso ya que alguien puede verla, ya sea navegando en tu historial o *scrolleando* hasta verla.

Un excolega, que también es becario como yo, hizo eso, y cuando me tocó limpiar su computadora, vi en su historial el comando `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -placontraseña` en una base de datos de producción... es de esas cosas que primero te ríes y luego te preocupas. Imagina que un sysadmin malvado la ve, ahora imagina que esa contraseña también es la del servidor o la de la computadora programador por el típico reciclado de contraseñas...

Una forma, aunque tediosa, de mitigar ese asunto de la seguridad, es quitar la contraseña al lado del parámetro `-p` y así, `mysqldump`, preguntará por la contraseña cada base de datos que consulte. Esto deja de ser tedioso cuando usas el `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql` ya que ahí sólo te la pedirá una vez para todas las bases de datos y no por cada una.

Otra forma de abordar el tema es que, después de escribir información sensible, utilizar el comando `history -c` en `bash`.

Otra forma de solucionarlo es editando el archivo `~./my.cnf` y añadiendo la entrada `[mysqldump]` con las respectivas configuraciones, por ejemplo.

```
[mysqldump]
user     = <usuario>
password = <contraseña>
host     = <host>
port     = <puerto>
```

Osea, al final te tendría que quedar algo así, sólo es un decir.

```
[mysqldump]
user     = root
password = asdlkfmasdkmacsdcasContraseña
host     = 127.0.0.1
port     = 3306
```

Y listo, cualquiera de las respuestas que escribí anteriormente se pueden correr **sin los parámetros**, como `-h <host>`, `-u <usuario>`, `-p` , `-p<contraseña>`, `-P <puerto>`, ya que estos se tomarán de ese archivo de configuración. Claro, este archivo puede ser leído pero para eso le cambias los permisos a `600` con `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf` para darle permisos sólo de lectura y escritura únicamente al usuario que le pertenece ese archivo.

Esta última forma es claro que cualquiera que tenga permisos de superusuario la puede ver, así que depende de la seguridad del sistema que manejes. Si no te gusta, puedes recurrir a poner la contraseña a mano cuando `mysqldump` o `mysql` te lo pidan.

Comment: gracias encontre la solucion a mi caso usando -h